# Where do I get Two Letter Domain Name?

Tags: domain, web, web-services

For my business purpose I want to take a Two letter domain name(eg: xx.yy). Where do I get this? 
I think GoDaddy.com doesn't support two letter domain names?

**my name is not yet registered, thank God its available!!!!**

Comment: You have asked a bunch of questions, but not accepting any answers. It's give and take here.

Comment: Who says i is vailable? it could be unavailable per policy.

Comment: @TomTom +1, such as the .com, .net, .org, .us domains which now prohibit two letter domains. If it's not taken, it's probably can't be taken.

Comment: At this point, any unregistered two-letter domain has a *reason* it's unregistered. It's highly unlikely you'll be able to get it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the particular extension, but these two sites may help:

http://www.register.com/
http://www.enom.tv/domain-registration/

Comment: i need something like bit.ly .. ".ly" :(

Comment: The .ly extension does not support two-letter domain names: http://www.marcaria.com/register/domain/domain_registration.asp?country=Libya&curr=EUR&gclid=CKStxp_3hqQCFUWQzAod7mXIJA

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy doesn't offer .ly because .ly is a country-code TLD for Libya. You can register your .ly domain name here:

http://www.ltt.ly/en/personal/hosting/index.php?c=13